# Strange behavior with Magellan Fixed | Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation, magellan

I am trying to create a product summary (sidebar) like Apple's when you purchase a product. I am using Magellan and it seems to break the page at any width below 960 pxs. It may have something to do with the table. I am not sure any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Like the photo below:

[image].

```
<div data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
    <div class="large-2 columns right" >
        <div id="top">
            <h5>Summary</h5>
            <h4>Business Cards</h4>
        </div>

        <div id="summary">
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td>Digital</td></tr>   
                    <tr><td>3.5 * 2</td></tr>     
                    <tr><td>Qty: 50,000</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>14 Point C2S</td></tr>
                    <tr><td>Color Front, Empty Back</td></tr>      
                    <tr><td>5 Business day turnaround</td></tr>    
                    <tr><td>5 Business day turnaround</td></tr>  
                    <tr><td>5 Business day turnaround </td></tr>
                </tbody>
             </table>

             <h5>Your Price:      $64.5</h5>
             <h5> Unit Cost:      $0.323</h5>
             <a href="#" class="small radius success button">Get Started</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one problem witch could be the table width. Try to add  `#top table { width: 100%;}`

As you are using F5 and it is not supporting old IE browser you can implement more HTML5 and CSS3 structure:

```
<data-magellan-expedition="fixed">
<section id='business' class='large-3 medium-12 columns right'>
    <header>
        <h1>Summary</h1>
        <p>Business Cards</p>
    </header>
    <article>
        <table class='debug'>
            <tbody>
                 <tr><td>Digital</td></tr>   
                 <tr><td>3.5 * 2</td></tr>     
                 <tr><td>Qty: 50,000</td></tr>
                 <tr><td>14 Point C2S</td></tr>
                 <tr><td>Color Front, Empty Back</td></tr>      
                 <tr><td>5 Business day turnaround</td></tr>    
                 <tr><td>5 Business day turnaround</td></tr>  
                 <tr><td>5 Business day turnaround </td></tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
       <p class='price'>Your Price:      </p>
       <p class='price'> Unit Cost:      </p>
       <a href="#" class="small radius success button">Get Started</a>
    </article>
</section>
</div>
```

It is little more semantic and it have more logical outline. You can that target tags inside the #business:

```
#business table { width: 100% }
#business > header {}
#business > article {}
#business > header > h1 {}
```

Example markup to match you example:

```
.debug {border: 1px solid red;}
/* Bussines root modifiers */
#business table { width: 100%;}

/* Bussines #top */
#business > header {
    /* Target former #top */
}

#business > header > h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#business > header p {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

/* Business #summary */

#business > article {
    /* Target former summary */
}

/* Price specs */
.price {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0px; padding: 0px;
}
.price:last-of-type {margin-bottom: .5rem;}
```

Github gist > https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8915089

If it's not solving your problem post more informations. Like whera are the checkboxes from image and so.

Comment: Also it uses F5 new medium grid. In testing magellan did't affect the section at all.

Comment: Also it occured to me that Magellan is intended to be uses as "sticky-navigation" ... What you are trying to accomplish is Sidebar staying on trough scroll in view isn't it?
If that's the case magellan will not help ... instead use position: fixed in your CSS